# How can I have my DebuggerTypeProxy target class inherit from base proxies?

Tags: c#, .net

**Question:**
I'm looking for a way to simplify the construction of debugger type proxies for inherited classes. So, when debugging a class that inherits from another, I should see the properties of both side-by-side: the base properties of the base class, plus the new properties of the parent class.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. `NewA`'s type proxy inherits from that of `A`. Properties don't show side-by-side; base properties are umbrella'd [sic] under `Base`. <sup>*****</sup>
2. Including an `A` property in `NewA` that just casts the current `NewA` to `A`, with `[DebuggerBrowsable(RootHidden)]`: Visual Studio hangs :(

I know that I could just add properties for the base class into `NewA`'s proxy, but I'm trying to avoid this. It's too much work for classes with many properties.

---

**Explanation:**

I'm using the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute on some of my classes so I can control how the class looks when browsed during debugging. For example:

```
public class A {
    private String _someField;

    public String SomeField {
        get {return _someField;}
    }
}
```

By default, the tooltip debugging info shows as:

[image]

... so I use a DebuggerTypeProxy to hide the backing field:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(AProxy))]
public class A {
    // ...

    internal class AProxy {
        A _a;
        AProxy (A a){
            _a = a;
        }

        public String SomeField {
             get {return _a.SomeField;}
        }
    }
}
```

... all is right with the world:

[image]

---

Now, I create a class that inherits from A.

```
public class NewA : A {
    private String _anotherField;
    public String AnotherField {
        get {return _anotherField;}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when debugging this class, Visual Studio uses the base type proxy (from `A`). This means we can see the base `SomeField` property, but our new `AnotherField` property is hidden (unless you expand `Raw View`, of course):

[image]

Removing the type proxy from base `A` results in `AnotherField` showing, but not `SomeField`.

---

**<sup>*</sup> Failed attempt #1**

```
/// <summary>
/// The base class
/// </summary>
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(AProxy))]
public class A {
    private String _someField;

    public String SomeField {
        get { return _someField; }
    }

    protected class AProxy {
        A _a;
        protected AProxy(A a) {
            _a = a;
        }

        String SomeField {
            get { return _a.SomeField; }
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Parent class
/// </summary>
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(NewAProxy))]
public class NewA : A {
    private String _anotherField;
    public String AnotherField {
        get { return _anotherField; }
    }

    // Inherit base type proxy, in an effort to display base properties
    // side-by-side with AnotherField: Doesn't work.
    protected class NewAProxy : A.AProxy {
        NewA _newA;
        protected NewAProxy(NewA newA)
            : base(newA) {
            _newA = newA;
        }

        public String AnotherField {
            get { return _newA.AnotherField; }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Still doesn't work. Base properties are not placed side-by-side with the new properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of searching and tinkering, I found the solution - and a beautiful one at that - [from Jared Par's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/02/19/flattening-class-hierarchies-when-debugging-c.aspx). He creates a type proxy that uses reflection to condense all the members into one list. Some additional `DebuggerDisplay` magic makes it so you don't even notice.

```
// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/02/19/flattening-class-hierarchies-when-debugging-c.aspx
// by Jared Par
internal sealed class FlattenHierarchyProxy {

    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}", Name = "{Name,nq}", Type = "{Type.ToString(),nq}")]
    internal struct Member {
        internal string Name;
        internal object Value;
        internal Type Type;
        internal Member(string name, object value, Type type) {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Type = type;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly object _target;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private Member[] _memberList;

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    internal Member[] Items {
        get {
            if (_memberList == null) {
                _memberList = BuildMemberList().ToArray();
            }
            return _memberList;
        }
    }

    public FlattenHierarchyProxy(object target) {
        _target = target;
    }

    private List<Member> BuildMemberList() {
        var list = new List<Member>();
        if ( _target == null ) {
            return list;
        }

        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var type = _target.GetType();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(flags)) {
            var value = field.GetValue(_target);
            list.Add(new Member(field.Name, value, field.FieldType));
        }

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(flags)) {
            object value = null;
            try {
                value = prop.GetValue(_target, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                value = ex;
            }
            list.Add(new Member(prop.Name, value, prop.PropertyType));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

---

**Modifications**

I made three little modifications to the class to make it more usable for me.

First, I wanted the members sorted by name. To do this, change the last line to:

```
return list.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
```

Second, in the `Member` struct, I added some attributes so that only the value would show when you expand a reference class:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
internal string Name;
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
internal object Value;
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
internal Type Type;
```

Third, the default flags `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` mean that even members marked `[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]` will still be shown. To prevent this from happening, after this line:

```
foreach (var field in type.GetFields(flags)) {
```

add this:

```
// Respect DebuggerBrowsableAttributes
var debuggerBrowsableAtts = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggerBrowsableAttribute), true);
if (debuggerBrowsableAtts.Count() == 1) {
    var att = debuggerBrowsableAtts[0] as DebuggerBrowsableAttribute;
    if (att.State == DebuggerBrowsableState.Never) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Now the `DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)` will be respected for fields. You can also add that code the foreach loop that handles properties, to have it respected for properties as well.

Comment: you can also enable DebuggerBrowsableAttributes for the properties.